# C++ how to use a pointer which has been created in a subroutine

Tags: c++, pointers, subroutine

or Mrs.,
in C++, I'm thinking about using a subroutine to define all my pointers first declared in my main body. I know it can be done by using functions to return one pointer each time. Hence, I still want to do it in a subroutine. I googled much and haven't found a answer yet. Your help is appreciated. 
An sample c++ code is as:

---

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void  testsub(int* k3d)
{
k3d= new int [10];
cout<<"test 0 "<<k3d[0]<<endl;
}
int  main ()
{
int* i3d=0;
testsub(i3d);
cout<<"test 1 "<<i3d[0]<<endl;
}
```

---

I hope the i3d in the main body can be used after the dummy pointer k3d has been defined in the subroutine. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pointer needs to be passed in by reference, otherwise you're just changing a local copy of that pointer.

```
void testsub(int*& k3d)
```

Also you need to call `delete[]` after the `cout`statement, to avoid memory leaks:

```
delete [] i3d;
```

Comment: Perfect! it works as I hoped for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could `return` a pointer from a subroutine.

```
#include <iostream> 

int* testsub()
{
    int* ptr = new int[10];
    std::cout << "test 0 " << ptr[0] << std::endl;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int *i3d = testsub();
    cout << "test 1 " << i3d[0] << endl;
    delete[] i3d;
    return 0;
}
```

Or use a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to hold a collection of integers. In this case you don't need to worry about memory allocations/deallocations too.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> i3d(10);
    std::cout << "test 1 " << i3d[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like that pointers created inside subroutine relate to the memory, common to a whole program, but not only to a memory used by subroutine, like common variables.